# Is there a rule that states that complex access methods are evil?

Tags: java, getter-setter, getter, access-control

Adding more functionality to access methods (getters/setters) than simply `this.x = x;` or `return x;` is usually considered bad style.

I am looking for a written source which I can reference in a technical paper. The [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) does not contain a statement about the content of access methods. Neither does the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Is there any official Oracle document or something similar with high significance that explicitly states that? Or is just an unwritten law?

**EDIT:** Seems like I was wrong about "usually considered bad style." I did not want to start a discussion about an opinion based topic. For me, my answer is that I cannot assume it is considered bad style. Thanks for your input!

Comment: "is usually considered bad style" well, if you're struggling to find a reference here, are you sure it is? I mean, it's a kinda self-fulfilling definition: if it's a method to access a property of a class, it should just access that property of the class, and if it does anything else it's too complex.

Comment: Making variables accessible through an accessor is a pattern **so that** you can add functionality or change functionality. As long as the functionality is related to the original functionality (such as sending property change events, doing validation, etc) there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, by nature, an opinionated view, but I was under the opposite impression.  If indeed getter/setter were limited to simple return/assignment, then they would serve no added value then the direct approach.

It is quite common and expected of setter to have some validation.

also, getter method can be created for calculated fields (like getSum(), getAvg(), etc) and in this case, they may include a simple or complex calculations.

Comment: in other words, they may start with a straightforward content, and evolve into more complex code. IMO, same reasoning as already stated.

Answer (score 1):

As @SharonBenAsher wrote this topic is quite opinion based and I stand for the opposite opinion.

IMHO the are two basic types of classes: *Data Transfer Objects* (DTOs / Beans) and others. Only DTOs should have getters (and less often) setters by default. "Other" classes should have getters only when there is a good reason why you need to violate the *information hiding* principle.

But why should't they have (complex) logic?

My reason is: it violates the *single responsibility* pattern. The responsibility of a DTO is to carry data. The responsibility of verifying the data consistency or do some calculation on them belongs to the code that uses/fills the DTOs.

> so why have getter/setter? why not just access directly? make the DTO like a C structure – Sharon Ben Asher

Because of the *information hiding principle*.

Just because you have a DTO it does not mean that you have to store the values in some distinct member variables, it could be a collection.

Also a DTO could consist of other DTOs:

```
class Circle{
    private Point center;
    private double radius;
    Circle(double x, double y, double r){
      center = new Point(x,y);
      radius=r;
    }
    getX(){return center.getX();}
    getY(){return center.getY();}
    getRadius(){return radius;}
}
```

When accessing the properties directly you have to be aware of that *and* you cannot change it later...

> I fail to see how a class that validates its state violates the single responsibility pattern. it may call on a utility or some external class to help in the validation process, – Sharon Ben Asher

which is even worse. A utility class is a *hidden dependency* that you add to the next layer where you deliver your DTO to. This may not be a problem as long as this "next layer" is withing the same JVM, but what if that is on the other end of a network conection?

> but one cannot say it is categorically unresponsible for this task.  – Sharon Ben Asher

Did I?

I for myself think thatthe reasons I have are heavy enough to do it my way. If you disagree, It's fine for me.

> it depends on the design and specific situation. Same with creation. Sometimes you delegate the responsibility to a factory method, sometimes you will directly call a constructor.  – Sharon Ben Asher

But what if situation changes (as it usually does while applications develop)? My approach to separate validation from data structure will *always* work.

> I think your sample code is a good example of a non-simple getter... – Sharon Ben Asher

But it does not have *complex* logic.

Comment: so why have getter/setter? why not just access directly? make the DTO like a C structure

Comment: I fail to see how a class that validates its state violates the single responsibility pattern. it may call on a utility or some external class to help in the validation process, but one cannot say it is categorically unresponsible for this task. it depends on the design and specific situation. Same with creation. Sometimes you delegate the responsibility to a factory method, sometimes you will directly call a constructor.

Comment: I think your sample code is a good example of a non-simple getter...